# Update record in a second column based on a condition on other column

Tags: sql

I have a table like this. What I want to do is, when my Class has Value T, it should update all records with T for a particular task, if not replace Value as I.

Raw Data:

| Class | Value |
| --- | --- |
| AB | T |
| CD | B |
| AB | C |
| AB | A |
| CD | T |
| AC | A |

Expected Result

| Class | Value |
| --- | --- |
| AB | T |
| CD | T |
| AB | T |
| AB | T |
| CD | T |
| AC | I |

How Can I do this using SQL

Comment: You would use an `update` and a correlation using `exists`

Comment: What engine are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Postgresql, etc.?

Comment: Where's your SQL?  We can't understand what problem you're encountering with your query if you don't show us the query and explain what results you are getting versus what results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should serve the purpose.

```
UPDATE raw_table a
set value = 'T'
where EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM raw_table b 
   where b.class = a.class
   and b.value = 'T');
   
UPDATE raw_table a
set value = 'I'
where EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM raw_table b 
   where b.class = a.class
   and NVL(b.value, 'X') != 'T');
```